# In SQL can a sequenced range selection be done more efficiently than my algorithm (see code) that uses a cursor?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, performance, algorithm

I need to collapse multiple ranges of sequential numbers (1 or more) to sets of their minimum and maximum values. I have unique integers (no duplicates) stored in a table column.

The obvious way (to me) to solve this problem is to use a `cursor` (see my algorithm below) and iterate through every integer. However, it seems inefficient to me so I am wondering if there is a more efficient algorithm. Perhaps there is a way using common table expressions with recursion. I have more than 32767 integers though, so any solution will need to use `option (MAXRECURSION 0)` which sets unlimited recursion.

Following is a simplified test case for my existing algorithm usign a `cursor`. It will output the minimum and maximum for each range of sequential numbers (e.g. 1-3, 9-11, 13-13, 15-16).

I am using MS SQL Server 2008. Please note comments begin with two dashes (--).

```
declare @minInt int, @maxInt int
declare @nextInt int, @prevInt int
--need a temporary table to store the ranges that were found
declare @rangeTable table (minInt int, maxInt int)
declare mycursor cursor for
select * from
(
    select 1 as id  union
    select 2 as id  union
    select 3 as id  union
    select 9 as id  union
    select 10 as id union
    select 11 as id union
    select 13 as id union
    select 15 as id union
    select 16 as id
) tblRanges
order by id--order is needed for this algorithm if used with generic data
open mycursor
--initialise new sequence
fetch next from mycursor into @minInt
select @maxInt = @minInt--set the min and max to the smallest value
select @prevInt = @minInt--store the last int
declare @sequenceFound int
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin

    select @sequenceFound=1--set the default flag value to true
    --loop while sequence found
    while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 and @sequenceFound = 1
    begin

        fetch next from mycursor into @nextInt
        if @nextInt = (@prevInt + 1)
        begin
            select @sequenceFound = 1
        end
        else
        begin
            select @sequenceFound = 0
        end
        select @prevInt = @nextInt--store the current value as the previous value for the next comparison
        if @sequenceFound = 1 --if the nextInt is part of a sequence, then store the new maxInt
            and @maxInt < @nextInt--should always be true for ordered output containing no duplicates
        begin
            select @maxInt = @nextInt
        end

    end--while sequenceFound
    --store the sequence range and then check for more sequences
    insert into @rangeTable (minInt,maxInt) values (@minInt,@maxInt)
    --store the current value as the new minInt and maxInt for the next sequence iteration
    select @minInt = @nextInt
    select @maxInt = @nextInt
end--while more table rows found
select * from @rangeTable

close mycursor
deallocate mycursor
```

Comment: eeeekk! ........ use a Numbers or Tally Table...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I think you are onto something because a tally table would promote set based programming. Could you let me know how a tally table would help me to get the min and max values of each sequential range? A code sample would help me to understand what you mean, or a set based algorithm. If it makes it easier, I will accept correct pseduocode and post my derived implementation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of Itzik Ben-Gan:

```
WITH tblRanges AS
( 
    SELECT 1 AS ID  UNION 
    SELECT 2 AS ID  UNION 
    SELECT 3 AS ID  UNION 
    SELECT 9 AS ID  UNION 
    SELECT 10 AS ID UNION 
    SELECT 11 AS ID UNION 
    SELECT 13 AS ID UNION 
    SELECT 15 AS ID UNION 
    SELECT 16 AS ID 
),
StartingPoints AS
(
SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS rownum
FROM tblRanges AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM tblRanges AS B
WHERE B.ID = A.ID - 1)
),
EndingPoints AS
(
SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS rownum
FROM tblRanges AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM tblRanges AS B
WHERE B.ID = A.ID + 1)
)
SELECT S.ID AS start_range, E.ID AS end_range
FROM StartingPoints AS S
JOIN EndingPoints AS E
ON E.rownum = S.rownum;
```

You can read a full explanation from his chapter in `SQL Sever MVP Deep Dives` called [Gaps and Islands](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/nielsenMEAP_freeCh5.pdf). He explains various techniques (including cursors) and compares them in terms of performance.

Comment: Thank you. Your code works perfectly with the sample data and my real data. I really like how you have solved the problem without using a cursor.